# How to check day is between to days in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have two fields in mysql like following,

```
Id from_day to_day
1   2       6
2   1       4
3   4       5
```

from_day and to_day is current day like Mon is 1 and Sun is 7.

Now I want to check if id 2 is in current day like today is Wed(3). How I can check with mysql query.

Comment: What you did till now? What is your code? Updated your question by edit.

Comment: and why to use number for day ??!

Comment: Kindly show your code.or u can  define your  current day and then use query where current day  between from_day to to_day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$day_number = date('N');  // here $day_number returns the day 3 for today's date
```

and use mysql `between` to check whether it lies between `from_day` and `two_day` like:

```
"SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ".$day_number ." BETWEEN from_day AND two_day";
```

Comment: This will not give the desired results

Comment: @akbansa it works and it is a clean solution. You can easilly upgrade it to have day_number from a user input or from some logic

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether [`DAYOFWEEK(CURDATE())`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) is between `from_day` and `to_day` column values using a `CASE` expression.

**Query**

```
select 
  case when dayofweek(curdate()) between `from_day` and `to_day` then 'yes' 
  else 'no' end as `status`
from `your_table_name`;
```